Unable to "control collapsed by expression" of group boxes in QGIS Feature forms
In QGIS attribute forms we should be able to control the visibility/collapsing of containers (tabs/group boxes) with an expression (QGIS Documentation 16.1.9.1, The drag and drop designer, 5.2., cp. https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#the-drag-and-drop-designer).
However, this seems to work fine for tabs. Here we can select an attribute:

... or create an expression on which the visibility depends (note that we can select an object to preview the expression result):

These do not work for "control collapsed by expression" for group boxes. Neither can we select an attribute ...

... nor do we have objects to preview an expression result (which is always NULL) in the expression builder:

As one can see, I would like to make visibility/collapsing depend on the number of child objects in 1:n relations (no children -> collapsed, 1 or more children -> not collapsed).
Note that both latter examples are from the form definition of the same layer!
So what are we doing wrong? Are we missing something or is this a fat buggy bug?
I tested this with QGIS 3.34.9/10 LTR and QGIS 3.38.2.
We just realized that we can control collapsing by simply writing one of the expressions 1 or 0 into the field, which collapses the group box or even not. So this seems to work "somehow" but this cannot be intended behavior.

I don't know if it is an intended behaviour or a bug, but it seems that the usual variables associated with the current feature being evaluated are not exposed to the expression builder of the Group Box. You can test this by entering @feature as the expression. It returns NULL in the Preview. Therefore, any expression that relies on attributes, or in this case, relations of a feature, always evaluates to NULL and the required 1 or 0 (true or false) are never returned. Oddly enough, using $currentfeature returns <feature: -9223372036854775808>
